# dynamic div container with multiple content

Tags: html, css

i try to make a kind of banner with css. the div contain two images and a bit text splittet into two lines.
it looks good on my display but if i load the side on an other display with a smaller resolution and/or 4:3 the whole container is "falling appart" :(
i have tried different methodes but nothing seems to work. may be some of you can point me in the right direction :)

here is the css and html:

CSS:

```
#head_box_banner {
position: absolute;    
height: 150px;
width: auto;
right: 13px;
left: 13px;
top: 4px;
background-color: #DBDBDB;
border-radius:3px;
}

.logo1 {
margin-top: 19px;
margin-left: 139px;
}

.logo2 {
margin-top: -112px;
margin-left: 1380px;
}

.text_banner_1 {
margin-top: -125px;
margin-left: 426px;
font-size: 46px;
color: #062916;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: comic, serif;
font-style: oblique;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc, 
           0 2px 0 #c9c9c9,
           0 3px 0 #bbb,
           0 4px 0 #b9b9b9,
           0 5px 0 #aaa,
           0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
           0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
           0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),
           0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
           0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
           0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
           0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);   
}  

.text_banner_2 {
margin-top: 12px;
margin-left: 668px;
font-size: 46px;
color: #062916;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: comic, serif;
font-style: oblique;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc, 
           0 2px 0 #c9c9c9,
           0 3px 0 #bbb,
           0 4px 0 #b9b9b9,
           0 5px 0 #aaa,
           0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
           0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
           0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),
           0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
           0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
           0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
           0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
   }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="head_box_banner">
                      <div class="logo1"><img src="png/logol.png" width="110" height="112" /></div>
                      <div class="text_banner_1">Förderverein Grundschule</div>
                      <div class="text_banner_2">Hindeburgstrasse e.V.</div>
                      <div class="logo2"><img src="png/logor.png" width="110" height="112" /></div>
```

Comment: Could you make a [tag:JSFiddle] demo?

Comment: Have a look at [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a banner for all browsers and resolutions, you should use percentages instead pixels... for example :

```
#head_box_banner {
position: absolute;    

height: yourheight%;

width: auto;
```

Note that you are using percentages for height and width only for the banner, not for the pictures.
PS: Try to play with height percentages to see how many percents are the best option for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick go here's what I think you were going for

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#head_box_banner {
position: absolute;    
height: 150px;
width: auto;
right: 13px;
left: 13px;
top: 4px;
background-color: #DBDBDB;
border-radius:3px;
min-width: 900px;

}

.logo1 {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 19px;
  margin-left: 19px;
}

.logo2 {
  margin-top:19px;
  float:right;
  margin-right: 19px;
}

.text_banner_1 {
font-size: 46px;
color: #062916;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: comic, serif;
font-style: oblique;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc, 
           0 2px 0 #c9c9c9,
           0 3px 0 #bbb,
           0 4px 0 #b9b9b9,
           0 5px 0 #aaa,
           0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
           0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
           0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),
           0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
           0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
           0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
           0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);   
}  

.title_container{
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.text_banner_2 {
margin-top: 12px;
margin-left: 250px;
font-size: 46px;
color: #062916;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: comic, serif;
font-style: oblique;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc, 
           0 2px 0 #c9c9c9,
           0 3px 0 #bbb,
           0 4px 0 #b9b9b9,
           0 5px 0 #aaa,
           0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
           0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
           0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),
           0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
           0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
           0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
           0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="head_box_banner">
                      <div class="logo1"><img src="png/logol.png" width="110" height="112" /></div>
          <div class="logo2"><img src="png/logor.png" width="110" height="112" /></div>

          <div class="title_container">
              <div class="text_banner_1">Förderverein Grundschule</div>
                          <div class="text_banner_2">Hindeburgstrasse e.V.</div>
          </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's what I did. First, I used floats for the pictures instead of specifying exactly where they're meant to be in pixels. This means they will 'float' to the right or left of the browser no matter the resolution or browser size and the margin is only used to specify the distance between them and the div containing them.

Next I moved the writing into its own div and text-aligned it center. This keeps the text in the center of the browser so you don't need to specify where the center is in pixels (as a rule you only want to specify a location in pixels if you know 100% how big the div containing it will be. In this case the browser window can be shrunk or the resolution can be changed which causes all the glitches you're seeing)

Finally I gave head_box_banner a min width of 900px. Even my fabulous changes will muck up when the window gets too small so to avoid that happening I've made sure the header will never be smaller than 900px. If it is, the user will have to scroll right to see the whole header. FYI there are better solutions to this  (look up responsive design)

Comment: thanks for your work. it looks good for me. :)
may be i can still a bit play with the settings to get it also on even smaller resolution to work.
but you brought me to the verry right way. :D
thanks a lot.